# jQuery Mobile style framework just for form elements?

Tags: css, forms

I want to style form elements but im finding I cant do everything I want with CSS as sometimes the browsers ignore the styles. jQuery Mobile seems to get around this by creating new divs and spans around form elements. I dont want to use the entire jQuery Mobile library and I dont believe its possible to just use this behavior from it. Are their any other frameworks / methods that standardize form elements cross device and allow you to style them how you want? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by **"sometimes the browsers ignore the styles"** ?? could you explain

Comment: One example is if you apply background-image to a select list its ignored in chrome.